# Addons Do Not Show Up in User Preferences

Tags: interface, add-on, customization

I have installed many addons in the past with no problem. However, after reinstalling Blender, it no longer detects the custom addons in the user preferences at all.

- I have used the manual "Install" button available in user preferences.
- I have tried installing both the zip and extracted folder.
- The "Testing" tab on the addon page is active.
- I have tried manually placing the folder into the addon folder.

Comment: When you attempt to install from a zip file, there should be messages either in the info window or on the system console that might give an indication.  Could you attempt such an install and go to the scripting tab to see if there are any info messages.  Also, could you use the Window menu to enable the System console and see if there are any messages on the console?  If so, please edit your question and cut'n'paste those message into it.  Finally, which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: "Modules Installed () from 'C:\\Users\\julia\\Desktop\\pymeshio-3.0.1.zip' into 'C:\\Users\\julia\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.0\\scripts\\addons'"

I believe I am using Blender 3.0. I tried using the system console, but it didn't seem to do anything (I am not too familiar with using the system console).

Comment: You are using 3.0 (it shows up in the modules message) and since you're on Windows, the System console is just a window that display output.  You can open it by going to the Window menu in the topbar and clicking _Toggle System Console_.  It may have some text.  But the message you quoted says that pymeshio was installed.

There have been reports of behavior similar to what you are seeing and it may be that the authors of pymeshio will have to update it for 3.0 before it will work.

Comment: I will try older versions of Blender for these addons. Thank you.

Comment: 2.93.6 should not have the problems and is the most recent older version.  Do let us know what you find out. pymeshio is definitely an old addon and unlikely to work with new versions of blender, but there should be error messages.

Comment: folders with dots inside tend to have issues being correctly recognized, you should remove them, it might help